# Why are these quantile values increasing, when the confidence percentage is increasing?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, quantiles

In R:

```
qnorm(.075, mean=11,sd=8.58) == -1.35
qnorm(.16, mean=11,sd=8.58) == 2.48
```

It's also strange to me that the first line is negative, but I assume that it's a technical issue.

Shouldn't the area under the pdf equal to .85 have a larger interval than the area equal to .68?

Comment: Quartile was an unfortunate typo for quantile in the title. Make sure that you realise that quartiles are a special case of quantiles.

Comment: I do, and it was an unfortunate mistake, thank you for correcting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you're asking R for:

> `qnorm(.075, mean=11,sd=8.58)`

[image: normal density showing 0.075 point]

> `qnorm(.16, mean=11,sd=8.58) == 2.48`

[image: normal density showing 0.16 point]

> Its also strange to me that the first line is negative, but I assume that its a technical issue.

It's not a "technical issue", that's actually what the quantile is. It's negative because the 0.075 point of a normal distribution is about 1.44 standard deviations below the mean. When the mean is 11 and the standard deviation is 8.58, you get 11.0 - 1.44 x 8.58 ≈ -1.35

> Shouldnt the area under the pdf equal to .85 have a larger interval than the area equal to .68?

Indeed it does, but you didn't compute that interval with that call to `qnorm`. You only computed the left end of that interval. The left end of the wider (/longer) interval is lower down, just as it should be.

Comment: A thorough answer. May you succeed where I failed.

Comment: @kodio I thought your answer was fine; I just figured the OP's misunderstanding was such that some explicit diagrams might be needed.

Comment: I came to give @Kodiologist an answer badge but your graphs helped so I ended up giving it to you. This is what I suspected, after Koddios explanation, I just coulddnt articulate myself properly. Thanks to both of you for helping me understand this :)

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you. My name is "Kodi", though, not "Kodio".

Comment: @Kod Sure, but I was not trying to name you I was trying to get the system to show you I was responding to you. The computer code doesn't differentiate between *Kodi* and *ologist* as words -- it just sees an `@` followed by an abbreviation of *Kodiologist* and if I typed enough characters for it to figure out it's you, it tells you I responded. I typed 5 characters to be sure it got there. Three should probably work though

Answer (score 1):

`qnorm(.075, mean = 11, sd = 8.58)` returns −1.35 because 7.5% of the mass of a normal distribution with mean 11 and SD 8.58 lies between −∞ and −1.35. If what you wanted is to compute the proprtion of this distribution's mass that lies between −∞ and .075, you want the CDF, which in R would be written `pnorm(.075, mean = 11, sd = 8.58)`.

Comment: Huh I thought that qnorm returns the z-score of some cdf value? Since z-score is used to create confidence intervals, a higher z-score means that there is a greater area covered around the mean for the confidence interval. So the lower cdf value (where <.5 )should correspond to a greater z-score.

Comment: You sound really confused. For one thing, `qnorm` will only return *z*-scores if you set `mean = 0, sd = 1`. For another, no confidence intervals are involved in this situation anywhere. To be specific, `qnorm` is the inverse CDF, also known as the quantile function (that's what the "q" stands for).

Comment: In the past Ive used the quantile function to find the number of standard deviations from the mean some quantile is. Are you saying that it returns the actual value of the pdf at the quantile instead?

Comment: No, the PDF is given by `dnorm` ("d" for "density"). The quantile function `qnorm(q, ...)` tells you the number `a` such that `pnorm(a, ...) == q`, that is, such that $(-∞, a)$ contains a proportion `q` of the mass of the normal distribution.